# How to check if a DateTime value is not null or empty?

Tags: powershell, datetime

I want to check if the DateTime field is not an empty\null string. if datetime field is not null then I will do stuff.

```
[DateTime]$expdate = Read-Host "Expiration Date? MM/DD/YYYY"
$newexpdate = $expdate.AddDays(1)
if (!([DateTime]$expdate -eq "")) {
    Write-Host -ForegroundColor Green $($newexpdate) "Date Time entered"
}
```

Here is my error message:

```
Cannot convert value "" to type "System.DateTime". Error: "String was not
recognized as a valid DateTime."
At line:1 char:2
+     [DateTime]$expdate = Read-Host "Expiration Date? MM/DD/YYYY"
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : MetadataError: (:) [], ArgumentTransformationMetadataException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : RuntimeException`
```

What can I do to check if a field is not a string but is `DateTime` object?

Comment: `if ($expdate) {"Has value"}  else {"No value"}` An empty string evaluates to `$false`.

Comment: You can check the datatype: ***$expDate -is [datetime]***

Comment: Declaring the variable as `[datetime]$foo` forces any assignment to it to be converted to a `datetime`. If it's not convertible, an error will be thrown, as you're seeing. Don't declare a type on `$foo`, and then you can test for a null string.

Answer (score 2):

Why prompt for user input when you can declare a mandatory `DateTime`-type parameter to a function or script? If the parameter is missing, PowerShell will prompt the user for the date and time and the user can enter it at runtime. (If you use `Read-Host`, you can't automate.)

Answer (score 0):

There is no empty [DateTime] value, it can either be a $null or a datetime value.

Read-Host returns string type. What you're trying to do is assigning string values to a [DateTime] type which will cause error.

You can rewrite your code like this:

```
$expdate = Read-Host "Expiration Date? MM/DD/YYYY"
if (![string]::IsNullOrEmpty($expdate))) {
   #add logic to check $expdate is valid datetime
   #then you can do this
   $newexpdate = ([DateTime]$expdate).AddDays(1)
   Write-Host -ForegroundColor Green $($newexpdate) "Date Time entered"
}
```

Comment: this does not Answer the Question ... it just restates it. [*frown*]

Answer (score -1):

Your logic doesn't make much sense, but here's what I *think* you're trying to do (below).  To directly address your last question, you can test the type of an object by using the `-is` or `-isNot` operator which will return `$True`\ `$False` depending on the match.  The other side of the operator can be a string or type accelerator, i.e. `[DateTime]'10/10/2010' -is 'DateTime'` or `[DateTime]'10/10/2010' -is [DateTime]` both evaluate to `$True`

```
Do
{
    $ExpDate = Read-Host -Prompt 'Expiration date? MM/DD/YYYY'
} Until ($ExpDate -match '\d{1,2}\/\d{1,2}\/\d{2,4}')

$NewExpDate = ([DateTime]$ExpDate).AddDays(1)

If ($ExpDate)
{
    Write-Host "$NewExpDate Date Time entered." -ForegroundColor 'Green'
}
```

Comment: first of all thanks for your answer. my question is :if the user hits enter with no input "Read-Host -Prompt 'Expiration date?"  nothing ,  if if the user hits enter with input "Read-Host -Prompt 'Expiration date?" then I will do stuff.

Comment: @Arbelac You can just do `If ($ExpDate) { do stuff } Else { error handling }`

Comment: But if the user hits enter with no input  for "$ExpDate = Read-Host -Prompt 'Expiration date? MM/DD/YYYY'  "  I got the following the error :  to type "System.DateTime". Error: "String was not recognized as a valid DateTime."

Comment: @Arbelac Don't try casting to datetime before you've done validation on the value then.